# C# equivalent of Excel's TINV function

Tags: c#, .net, excel, worksheet-function

I am porting over some code from Microsoft Excel to C#. The Excel expression uses the [TINV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828340) function. Is there an equivalent function in C# or .NET? If not, what C# code is necessary to reimplement this function?

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can leverage the Chart class found in the System.Web.DataVisualization assembly (you will also need to add System.Web). E.G:

```
var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
double result = chart.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseTDistribution(.05, 15);

//2.131449546
```

Documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula.inversetdistribution(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Excellent. That was exactly what I was after. A shame it's tied to UI code, but it will do for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing.

You can look the exact way up in Math.NET (MIT/X11).

```
double result  = MathNet.Numerics.ExcelFunctions.TInv (probability, degFreedom);
```

which is the same as:

```
double result  = -StudentT.InvCDF(0d, 1d, degFreedom, probability/2);
```