# How to calculate T.INV() in c# without excel workbook object

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, static-methods, static-analysis, class-library

How to calculate T.INV() in c# without excel workbook object. Is there any direct formula or class that can help me?.I have already Used "System.Web.UI.DataVisualization " namespace but it is not giving me expected result.
Thanks 
Shakeb Khan

```
public static double InverseTDistributionfun(int DF, double probability)
{
    double Tinv;
    try
    {
        chart.Charting.Chart objChart = new chart.Charting.Chart();
        Tinv = objChart.DataManipulator.Statistics.TDistribution(probability,DF, true);
        // value = c16 + dup * y30;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return Tinv;
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static double SQLCLRCsharpSP(int DF, double probability)
{  
    double _sum = 0.00; 
    try
    {

        //if (type == "C")
        _sum = InverseTDistributionfun(DF, probability);
        //if (type == "A")
            //_sum = AlgTInvFun(probability, DF);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return  _sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to use?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963192/c-sharp-equivalent-of-excels-tinv-function?

Comment: it is not duplicate TINV() and T.INV() are different function . It introduce in excel 2010 onward version.

Comment: In that case is this giving a two tail answer? You say it doesn't give the expected result. What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: In excel
1.475884=T.INV(0.9,5) which is I am expecting

but
1)0.20468560017491644
Tinv = objChart.DataManipulator.Statistics.TDistribution(.9, 5, true);
2)0.40937120034983288
  Tinv = objChart.DataManipulator.Statistics.TDistribution(.9, 5, false);

Comment: The answer of the post mentioned by @doctorlove propose to use `InverseTDistributionfun()` method. Why to you try `TDistribution()` method in your comment? You also need to consider the probably value, that you send to the `InverseTDistributionfun()`, should depends on one-sided or two-sided critical region using. See corresponding values of probability in [t-distribution quantile value table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). So, I agree the question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963192/c-sharp-equivalent-of-excels-tinv-function.

Answer (score 0):

You can look the exact way up in Math.NET (MIT/X11).

```
double result  = MathNet.Numerics.ExcelFunctions.TInv (probability, degFreedom);
```

which is the same as:

```
double result  = -StudentT.InvCDF(0d, 1d, degFreedom, probability/2);
```

You find the complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941949/sql-server-equivalent-of-excels-tinv-function/28061573#28061573).
If that doesn't return the same values, then you're not using the tinv function.